# Detecting async function calls completion in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, callback

Say,there is a requirement that a customer object is loaded from the db to a silverlight application, so that the customer details are shown in the UI. We need to detect if the user is changing any data in the UI.

We are listening to property changed notifications from the view model. However, when the notifications are result of property change as part of the loading process we have to discard it.

```
 class CustomerLoader
    {
    Helper helerobj;
    Address addressobj;
    Profile profileobj;
    void LoadFromDb()
    {

    helperobj.Load();
    addressobj.Load();
    profileobj.Load();
//start listening after the loading finished
    this.propertychanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(handlepropertychanged);


    }
```

The trouble with this is the inner objects might be calling asynchronous functions which might set properties. So by the time we started the property change listening, the loading might not have been finished.

We need to know when the loading is actually done. As of now we are asking the developers who are developing the inner object classes to accept a callback in the parameter which they should call when the function is finished.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want nothing but a really classic asynchronous objet loading.

So yes, the only solution is to ask developers working on the loading to propose an asynchronous function. Now you hav several solution to achieve asynchronicity in Silverlight.

You could either provide a callback as you do, or use async and await to manage your asynch task as explain here: http://10rem.net/blog/2012/05/22/using-async-and-await-in-silverlight-5-and-net-4-in-visual-studio-11-with-the-async-targeting-pack